# How can i properly use circular imports in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Context: I have a websocket 'server.py' and a script that executes some tasks: 'worker.py'. I want to use the functions in server.py to send the results from that task in worker.py. But the thing is, when a client requests the worker to send results, i need to use a function from worker.py. How can I avoid circular dependies in this situation?

Server.py:

```
import eventlet
#eventlet.monkey_patch()
import socketio
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
#The Worker file
import worker

sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='http://localhost:8100')

@sio.on('connect')
def connectHandler(sid, environ):
    print('[INFO] Incoming connection from: ' + environ['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    sio.emit('response', {'data' : 'Connection established, you can now request classifications by firing the "requestClassification" event.'})


@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnectHandler(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

@sio.on('requestClassification')
def requestHandler(data):
    print('[INFO] recieved request to classify')
    print(data)

    #using a function in the worker module
    worker.someFunc()

eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('127.0.0.1', 8080)), app)
```

worker.py:

```
import server

def work():
    while True:
        result = doSomeTask()
        print(f'sending result: {str(i)}')
        server.sio.emit('result', {'data' : result})
        server.sio.sleep(1)
```

How can i properly use the imports without defining sio (the server) twice for example?

Comment: 1) Use three files - server, worker, and helper functions. 2) If server is the main script then you could use the ```if __name__ == "__main__":```. 3) Have a function which creates the server, and call it in a ```main``` script instead of as a global call.

Comment: Move `import worker` inside `requestHandler`.

Comment: @ekhumoro moving import worker to the requestHandler results in the server being made twice

Comment: @FatihErtikin No it doesn't. All imports are cached in `sys.modules`.

Comment: @ekhumoro result: ```OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted```

Comment: @FatihErtikin My comment was based on the code you posted, and so remains correct as far as that goes. You probably need to show something more like a [mcve].

Comment: @FatihErtikin Actually, the same idea should work the other way around. Put `import server` inside `work`. However, if other parts of the `worker` module need to access the `server` module, you may need to split them out into a separate module. The real issue here is that you are putting too much code in the script that starts the application. It is usually best to keep it very minimal and have all the shared functionality in separate modules.

Comment: @ekhumoro okay thanks for the feedback, as suggested earlier i used ```if __name__ == '__main__``` to instantiate the server and that works, only problem now is that the worker file doesn't use the sio instance of server.py so it doesn't actually send the result.